# how to call the function when button is clicked using pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

i want to call the function when i want to clicked the button i cannot the understand what's i m doing wrong

but it gives me as error which given given below

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

```
class MyFirstWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Label = None
        self.Button = None
        super(MyFirstWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("My First Window GUI Application")
        self.ShowWidgets()

    def ShowWidgets(self):
        try:
            self.Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.Label.setText("My Name is Umair!")
            self.Label.move(170,70)
            self.Button.setText("Click Here")
            self.Button.move(160,30)
            self.Button.clicked(self.BtnClicked())
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))


    def BtnClicked(self):
        self.Label.setText("Label Text is Changed")


def ShowWindow():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyFirstWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


ShowWindow()
```

Comment: `button.clicked.connect(method)` look into signals and slots

Comment: that methods also does not work it also gives me an error

Comment: @UmairMubeen change to `self.Button.clicked.connect(self.BtnClicked)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `self.Button.clicked.connect(self.BtnClicked)`